# Link to duplicate question not present

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I'm not sure why, but it appears this question has no linked duplicate:
[How to create hoverover popups in Rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608962/how-to-create-hoverover-popups-in-rails-3-1)

[image]

Perhaps it's normal and I just haven't come across it before.

Comment: the last comment notes that "The currently shown duplicate has been deleted."

Comment: @toolic interesting, good spot. I guess it doesn't happen too often.

Comment: Here is the deleted duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534812/simple-tooltip-plugin-js-for-rails. You can find this is the revision history.

Comment: @Laurel I get a page not found here on SO. But I can see an older version here: https://web.archive.org/web/20101115142205/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534812/simple-tooltip-plugin-js-for-rails

Comment: *"I get a page not found here on SO"* only those with 10k+ reputation can view deleted posts. Don't worry, you're not far off. :)

Comment: I suppose this just doesn't happen often enough for there to be some specific protocol for the system to handle it. It looks like the dupe-closure has since been removed, and the question reopened.